# Failed to calculate the value of task ':device_info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Today when I build the flutter (`flutter version:2.8.0`) project in android studio 2021.2.1, shows error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':device_info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, /Users/foo/source/reddwarf/frontend/cruise-open/build/device_info/generated/ap_generated_sources/debug/out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@265a97d4) before task ':device_info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? Anyone facing the similiar issue? The lib device info in `pubspec.yaml` version is: `device_info: ^2.0.0`. This is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```